# Regularized polynomial regression

Tags: optimization, regression, regularization

I observe a set of $n$ observations $(X_i,Y_i)$, $X_i, Y_i$ are both scalars. I wish to construct an optimization criterion which

- for low values of the tuning parameter $\lambda$ produces a cubic fit to the data and
- for high values of $\lambda$ produces an exact linear fit to the data

My proposed answer is
$$\operatorname{argmin}_\beta \sum_i(Y_i-\beta_1 X_i-\beta_2X_i^3)^2+\frac{1}{\lambda}||\beta_1||+\lambda||\beta_2||$$
where $||\bullet||$ is $L_1$ norm.

and I am not sure if it is legit. Also the question asks to draw (on a single plot) three example curves ($\lambda=0,\lambda=\infty, 0<\lambda<\infty$ that might be produced by the criterion and I am not sure which curve should I draw.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For a general cubic you will also need $X_i^2$ and for both you will need a constant term too. Maybe you already know this, but don't want those terms?

Comment: You also want to put something that makes the first sum 0 if you have a perfect fit. As it is written now -infinity would be optimal. Maybe you mean to sum up $(Y_i - \beta_1 X_i - \beta_2 X_i^3)^2$ or $|Y_i - \beta_1 X_i - \beta_2 X_i^3|$ ? If nothing prevents negative values then the objective function would not be bounded below.

Comment: I am missing the square sign. Corrected! For $X_i^2$ term, should I also penalize its coefficient with the coefficient of $X_i^3$ term, something like $\lambda||\beta_2+\beta_3||_1$?